# Vaadin: How to focus on first row after updating the grid in Vaadin?

Tags: java, grid, focus, vaadin

i'm building a Vaadin application with a Grid table within. The application reloads and updates every minute the table. `SelectionMode.NONE` and `v-grid-row-focused` are used. Unfortunately, the focus on the first row in the grid table disappears after each data refreshing.After some analysis I found out that after each table reloading the grid returns to `v-grid-cell-focused`-mode and only after pressing the arraydown-button for scrolling down the row focus it changes to the `v-grid-row-focused`-mode. Is there a way to completely disable `v-grid-cell-focused`-mode?

Comment: My understanding of `SelectionMode.NONE` is that no rows will be selected in the grid, yet you seem to be wanting a row selected. Can you please clarify what you're trying? Also, have you tried this hack after repopulating the grid       `grid.select(grid.getContainerDataSource().getIdByIndex(0));` ?

Comment: yes the table do not select row but focusing on the rows . somebody has programmed in that way.  selection is diabled and row focusing is displayed with colored and thicker borders.

Comment: In that case you need to share some code (a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) so we can see what it's all about.

Comment: `Select()` highlights the row... but focused cell still remains as it was. Is there a way to change the focused cell as well? I.e. the one with "blue" borders around it?

Comment: What about to focus the grid @TatuLund

Answer (score 1):

to get the 1st itemId (not Item) of a Table or Grid, you must go through the `Container.firstItemId`

Tables has an assessor method to this, but Grid doesn't

The solution proposed by **Morfic** won't work always, because the integer autogenerated by the containers when you use addItem() with no parameters (Indexed and Hierarchical) is incremental, if u clean/remove all/some items, the index will keep growing (not reset to 0) AND the index STARTS from 1, not 0 (if you check the source code), or if your implementation has the capacity to *remove Items from the Container* and the 1st one is removed, the ZERO index won't exist anymore

```
grid.select(grid.getContainerDataSource().getIdByIndex(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in Grid to set focused cell from server side. However I added such method setFocusedCell(row,col) in [GridFastNavigation add-on extension](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gridfastnavigation-add-on) for Vaadin 8.

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/gridfastnavigation-add-on